# sh kill illegal number : Kill parallel process

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, kill, pid

I am trying to open multiple parallel processes on a C++ program using. The four of them have to run in parallel. But when my C++ program closes, I want to kill each process. This is my attempt:

```
system("python okcsend.py & PID1=$! python okccnysend.py & PID2=$! python okc.py & PID3=$! python okccny.py & PID4=$!");
```

And when trying kill them, this is what I do:

```
system("kill PID1; kill PID2; kill PID3; kill PID4");
```

However, this is what I get:

```
sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: PID1
sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: PID2
sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: PID3
sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: PID4
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Err, `kill $PID1; ...`? But the $PID variables are probably lost in the environment of the original `system()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get back the PID from each process separately.

Pseudo code:

```
pid1 = system("python okcsend.py & echo $!)
pid2 = system("python okcsend.py & echo $!)
pid3 = system("python okcsend.py & echo $!)
pid4 = system("python okcsend.py & echo $!)
```

then you could do something like:

```
system("kill " + pid1 + "; kill " + pid2 + "; kill " + pid3 + "; kill " + pid4 + ";");
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when I used the "lsof" command. When I used "pidof" instead the problem was solved. Maybe it will give you an idea to solve this issue.

"lsof" may corrupt characters when used with the ssh command. There is no such problem for "pidof".